# Installing basic Gnome GUI on server

Tags: server, gnome, xorg, x11

I'm trying to install a very minimal Gnome environment on an Ubuntu server running on minimal server hardware (i.e. no graphics card) behind a KVM switch. Yes, I know that's generally frowned upon. I read the wiki's [Server GUI notes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI), but it only mentions how to install the entire desktop environment, not just the core.

So I ran `sudo apt-get install gnome-core xinit xorg` then rebooted. Afterwards, it came back up to a terminal login, which is fine. I logged in and then tried running `startx`, but received the error:

```
(EE) Failed to load module "ast" (module does not exist)
(EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
(EE) VESA(0): V_BIOS address 0x5f6e0 out of range
(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.

Fatal error:
no screens found
```

I read [here](http://alexsleat.co.uk/2011/03/04/how-to-fix-fatal-server-error-no-screens-found-ubuntu/) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1742700) that I should try deleting my /etc/X11/xorg.conf and rebooting, but the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf does not exist on my system.

What else do I need to do to resolve this error and get Gnome running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried generating an xorg.conf file since you don't have one? [Check this link for the command and documentation.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config)